# Convert Shell date format to Python date format

Tags: python, shell, date, datetime, date-formatting

Can below piece of shell date format be converted to python date format?

```
date_used = $(date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) - 1 month" "+%Y_%m")
```

As per my understanding this above format is just taking day as 15 of current month and it simply subtracts 1 month and results in giving output in the format of year_month.

Output of the above shell date format -->

```
echo $date_used = 2022_05
```

Can this particular scenario be done using python?

Any update about it would be really appreciable.

Comment: Take a look at the *datetime* module and the *strptime* and *strftime* functions in particular

Comment: so basically you're looking to subtract one month from the current date and convert that to a string with format yyyy_mm ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equivalent would be:

```py
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

# Current date, replace date with 15, subtract 30 days and format
date_used = (datetime.now().replace(day=15) - timedelta(days=30)).strftime('%Y_%m')
print(date_used)
```

Output:

```
2022_05
```

Comment: `days=30` isn't exactly a month at least half the time. Although now that I think about it, since you're always starting at the 15th it will give the correct answer.

Comment: `date_used = (date.today().replace(day=15) - relativedelta(months=delta_period) + timedelta(days=delta_period)).strftime('%Y_%m')`   .................this is working fine it seems.. any comments on this? we can delta_period as 1.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, that was my thought.   Even `.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)` would give the correct string.

Comment: @Saurabh `relativedelta` (from `dateutil` 3rd party library?) is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's `datetime` module to do this

it has a function named `strptime` you can use to read date and time data with format code very similar to unix date format (or maybe its even same i'm not sure)

and `strftime` to output in a certain format as well

you can see the functions and the format code to see if there's any different on
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Example code

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date = datetime.strptime((datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)).strftime("%Y-%m") + "-15", "%Y-%m-%d")
print(date)

print(date.strftime("%Y_%m"))
```

output

```bash
2022-05-15 00:00:00
2022_05
```

Comment: This seems okay but its not subtracting 1 month as asked in the question. Above answer is working. Thank u for trying @DavinderJolly

Comment: ah srry i missed the 1 month part :) but glad you found your answer. also i added the subtraction anyway :)